# Form validation does not work in Spring Mvc Application

Tags: spring, maven, validation, spring-mvc, tomcat9

I have a Spring Mvc Application using Spring 5.2.8.RELEASE, which is deployed in a Tomcat 9.0.37 instance.

The dependencies section of my pom.xml is the following:

```xml
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My WebConfig class (which is returned in the getServletConfigClasses()) is:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.example.myapp.web", "com.example.myapp.data"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

I have the following bean that contains some validation constraints:

```java
public class User {

    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, max = 16)
    private String firstName;

    ...
}
```

I have a JSP file for registering a new user:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register</h1>
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user">
    First Name: <sf:input path="firstName"/><br/>
    <!-- other fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</sf:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller that processes the request is the following:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

  // ...
  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = POST)
  public String processRegistration(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      return "registerForm";
    }
    userRepository.save(user);
    return "redirect:/user/" + user.getUsername();
  }
  // ...
}
```

The validation doesn't get triggered whenever I click the "Register" button in the browser.

However, when I invoke the method from a unit test, the validation is performed as expected (the test below fails because the redirection is not performed):

```java
public class UserControllerTest {

  @Test
  public void shouldProcessRegistration() throws Exception {
    UserRepository mockRepository = mock(UserRepository.class);
    User unsaved = new User("John", "Doe", "jdoe", "pass");
    User saved = new User(1L, "John", "Doe", "jdoe", "pass");
    when(mockRepository.save(unsaved)).thenReturn(saved);

    UserController controller = new UserController(mockRepository);
    MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();

    mockMvc.perform(post("/user/register")
      .param("firstName", "John")
      .param("lastName", "Doe")
      .param("username", "jdoe")
      .param("password", "pass"))
      .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/user/jdoe"));

    verify(mockRepository, atLeastOnce()).save(unsaved);
  }
}
```

UserController is in the web package, WebConfig in the config package and User in the package above these two (com.example.myapp).

Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong?

I have read all related questions on this problem, but wasn't able to find any solution for my problem.

Comment: I doubt the form is even going anywhere. Add an `action` to the form.

Comment: The form is going to the controller, I have checked this via debug. It is going to the same controller that generated it in the first place, if no explicit action is specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to figure it out.

It was not a code problem, but a project configuration one.

After adding some dependencies in the pom.xml (namely hibernate-validator and hibernate-validator-annotation-processor), the corresponding artifacts were not automatically added in the output directory in WEB-INF/lib by IntelliJ IDEA.

I had to add these libraries manually: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxIGT.jpg.

After doing so, the validation works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question.

Unit Test works and your form submit doesn't mean Your Data is not been set when you submit Form

Try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = POST)
public String processRegistration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

If the above doesn't work try adding a log to see if the value is been added to User Object.

Comment: I have also tried to use the @ModelAttribute annotation, but the result is the same. While inspecting the BindingResult in debug mode, I see the target field has the appropriate fields set up correctly, but without reporting any error -> see here: https://imgur.com/a/idOjVVd